# SpringBoot aplication "Not a managed type" exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Хотя со спрингом работаю уже давно, стокнулся с такой проблемой. Возможно это мелочь, которую я просто уже не вижу и нужен взгляд со стороны.

Имеется следующий код:

```java
package com.geeks.hashcoin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.geeks.hashcoin"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.geeks.hashcoin.domain")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HashcoinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HashcoinApplication.class, args);            
    }        
}
```

```java
package com.geeks.hashcoin;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.geeks.hashcoin.core.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("core");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {        
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("sql.database.driver.class.name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("sql.database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("sql.database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("sql.database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", env.getProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {

        final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }       
}
```

```java
package com.geeks.hashcoin.core.repository;

import com.geeks.hashcoin.domain.Orders;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author Админ
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders, Long> {
}
```

```java
package com.geeks.hashcoin.core.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author Админ
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderService {
}
```

```java
package com.geeks.hashcoin.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Админ
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column (name="order_id")
    private Integer orderId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}
```

Файл ресурсов:

```
#Servers(tomcat) port 
server.port=8080

#MySql settings
sql.database.driver.class.name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sql.database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
sql.database.username=root
sql.database.password=pass
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#Hibernates settings
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false

hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=false

hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF8MB4
```

Градл:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.geeks'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')   
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile group: 'com.github.derjust', name: 'spring-data-dynamodb', version: '5.0.2'//4.5.4
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.381' //1.11.360

    compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.5.0'
    compile group: 'cc.protea.foundation.http', name: 'http', version: '0.2'   
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'
}
```

При выполнении получаю исключение:

> `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.geeks.hashcoin.domain.Orders`

Подскажите, в чем проблема?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Можно полюбопытствовать почему так сложно? Для создания приложения на Spring Boot с поддержкой БД сейчас делается все намного [проще](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)...

Comment: Вот еще пример [от туда](https://spring.io/guides) же: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: Спасибо. Мне все таки хотелось бы разобраться с проблемой... Подскажите, если не затруднит, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Всем спасибо! Я нашел ошибку, это просто невнимательность.
Вся проблема в классе конфигурации базы данных в этой строке кода entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("core"); 
Здесь просто указано неправильное имя пакета.